# Text encoding - fine on Windows, not nix

Tags: linux, r, character-encoding, stringi

I have an issue with loading data between default encoding on Win and nix machines (ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 respectively).

Example - Windows first:

```
library(stringi)
dummy <- as.character("BØÅS")
write(dummy, "saveFile")
getData <- read.table("saveFile", header=F, sep="\t", quote="\"")

reEncode=function(x) {
  stri_trans_general(x, "Latin-ASCII")
}

enCoded  <- apply(getData, 1, reEncode)
result   <- as.data.frame(enCoded)
```

In Windows the above produces "BOAS" as desired.

Now move to nix and use the saved file:

```
getData <- read.table("saveFile", header=F, sep="\t", quote="\"")

    reEncode=function(x) {
      stri_trans_general(x, "Latin-ASCII")
    }

    enCoded  <- apply(getData, 1, reEncode)
    result   <- as.data.frame(enCoded)
```

Nix gives "B??S".

I believe this is a read.table encoding issue but haven't been able to figure out how to get nix to use ISO-8859-1.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ubuntu 14, `Sys.setlocal('LC_ALL', 'C');stri_trans_general("BØÅS", "Latin-ASCII")` gives `BOAS` for me. Can you put the output `Sys.getlocale()` in your post?

Comment: Hi Matthew.  I think we're identical: "LC_CTYPE=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
read.table("saveFile", header=F, sep="\t", quote="\"",encoding="latin1")
```